# Magento2: Error: Call to undefined method addViewsCount()

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

I have got the error below:

**Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::addViewsCount()**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Mostviewed\Block;

class Mostviewed extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    protected $_filesystem ;
    protected $_imageFactory;

protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {


    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get Product Collection of MostViewed Products
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getMostViewProductCollection()
{
    $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    // get today and last 30 days time
    $today = time();
    $last = $today - (60*60*24*30);

    $from = date("Y-m-d", $last);
    $to = date("Y-m-d", $today);

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addViewsCount()->setStoreId(
            $currentStoreId
        )->addStoreFilter(
            $currentStoreId
        )->setPageSize(10);

    $items = $collection->getItems();
    //var_dump($items);
    return $items;
}

// pass imagename, width and height
public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
{
    $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('custom_module/posts/').$image;
    if (!file_exists($absolutePath)) return false;
    $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;
    if (!file_exists($imageResized)) { // Only resize image if not already exists.
        //create image factory...
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
        $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
        //destination folder                
        $destination = $imageResized ;    
        //save image      
        $imageResize->save($destination);         
    } 
    $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;
    return $resizedURL;
  }

}
```

I want to get the most-view product collection. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong class

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
```

You should use the below class

```
\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
```

There is a difference between these two classes, the difference is module name changes to `Reports`

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: I have used same class which you provide. Got the same error.

Comment: There is a difference between the two classes, the difference is an only module name changes to `Reports`. Share your whole file code to the question if possible

Comment: Please check hole block code.

Comment: change this class in your construct method 

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory` 

to 

`\Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`

Comment: glad I could help